# Make terminal transparent to show wallpaper

Tags: terminal

The opacity option of the Gnome terminal in Ubuntu had a neat behavior, which showed the desktop wallpaper instead of the other windows behind it.

Has anyone been able to make Mac Terminal, or an alternative terminal app, do this?  I know you can set a terminal wallpaper, which squashes and stretches with the terminal window.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This can be done simply by typing this command in the terminal:

" defaults write com.apple.terminal TerminalOpaqueness '0.85' "

Without the quotes of course.

You can adjust the opaqueness level to whatever you like

Comment: The OP specifically wants to see the desktop wallpaper, not other windows behind the Terminal window. This is just a round-about way of changing the Opacity setting under Preferences > Settings.